# Mistake in a SQL statement

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to find this mistake:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '% ORDER BY
>   t1.nombre_cuenta ASC' at line 1

Where is it?. Thanks so much:

```
public Tdatoscuentas[] consultarCuentas(int id_tipo_cuenta){  //Acabar método para login

    Tdatoscuentas[] params = null; 

    try {
        this.conexion=conectar();
        System.out.println("Vamos a usar el id tipo cuenta:"+id_tipo_cuenta);
        int id_tipo_cuenta_padre=id_tipo_cuenta-1;
        //System.out.println();

        SQL="SELECT t1.id_cuenta as id_cuenta,"+     
                "t1.n_cuenta as n_cuenta,"+
           "SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.n_cuenta,'.',"+id_tipo_cuenta_padre+") as n_cuenta_padre,"+
           "t1.nombre_cuenta as nombre,"+         
           "(SELECT tt1.cif"+
           "  FROM cuentas_rs tt1"+
            " WHERE tt1.id_cuenta = t1.id_cuenta"+
            " ORDER BY tt1.f_inicio DESC "+
            " LIMIT 1) as cif,"+                          
            "(SELECT tt2.porcentaje "+
            " FROM impuestos tt2"+
            " WHERE tt2.id_pais = (SELECT tt1.cif"+
            "                     FROM cuentas_rs tt1"+
            "                     WHERE tt1.id_cuenta = t1.id_cuenta"+
            "                     ORDER BY tt1.f_inicio DESC"+
            "                     LIMIT 1)"+
            " ORDER BY tt2.f_inicio DESC "+
            "LIMIT 1)  as impuesto,"+
           "t1.descuento as descuento,"+      
           "t1.id_tipo_cuenta as nivel,"+          
           "t1.borrado  as borrado,"+        
           "t1.cod_cliente as cod_cliente "+     
           "FROM cuentas t1 "+
           "LEFT OUTER JOIN cuentas_rs t2 ON t2.id_cuenta = t1.id_cuenta"+ 
           " WHERE t1.id_esquema_asociado = 1"+  
           " AND t1.id_proveedor_cloud = 1"+
           " AND SUBSTRING(t1.n_cuenta,1,LENGTH(001.00001))"+
           " AND t1.id_tipo_cuenta =("+id_tipo_cuenta+")"+
           " AND t1.borrado = false"+         
           " AND t1.nombre_cuenta LIKE %" +         
           " ORDER BY t1.nombre_cuenta ASC";

        System.out.println("La consulta de SQL para consultar Cuentas es:"+SQL);
        this.pstm     = this.conexion.prepareStatement(SQL);

        this.rs =  pstm.executeQuery();

        this.rs.last(); 
        int numRows = this.rs.getRow(); 
        this.rs.beforeFirst();
        System.out.println("Vamos a hacer:"+numRows);
        params = new Tdatoscuentas[numRows];

        int i=0;
         while(this.rs.next()){
             params[i] = new Tdatoscuentas();
                params[i].setId_cuenta(this.rs.getInt("id_cuenta"));
                params[i].setN_cuenta(this.rs.getString("n_cuenta"));
                params[i].setN_cuenta_padre(this.rs.getString("n_cuenta_padre"));
                params[i].setNombre_cuenta(this.rs.getString("nombre"));
                params[i].setCif(this.rs.getString("cif"));
                params[i].setImpuesto(this.rs.getDouble("impuesto"));
                params[i].setDescuento(this.rs.getDouble("descuento"));
                params[i].setNivel(this.rs.getInt("nivel"));
                params[i].setBorrado(this.rs.getBoolean("borrado"));
                params[i].setCod_cliente(this.rs.getString("cod_cliente"));

            i++;        

            }
         System.out.println("params tiene una long de"+params.length);
         return params;  
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return params;  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation on [pattern matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

Change

> " AND t1.nombre_cuenta LIKE %" +

into

> " AND t1.nombre_cuenta LIKE '%'" +

I also second @podiluska's suggestion to look into using bind variables in your queries.

Comment: I agree - there wouldn't be any point on that line since it will match anything.  At least it's valid SQL.

Answer (score 3):

It's in the line `" AND t1.nombre_cuenta LIKE %" +`

I would also suggest reading up on how `preparestatement` is designed to work before you release this into the wild.

Comment: How do you put it?, with LIKE '%'?

Comment: @zolt: That would fix the syntax error, but it would match all strings (so what's the point in including such a filter criterion?).

Answer (score 1):

It is here:

```
...
AND t1.nombre_cuenta LIKE %" +  <---------- It is here       
           " ORDER BY t1.nombre_cuenta ASC
...
```

You have to add the string to match after the `%` and it must be quoted something like: `Like '%somevalue'`.

Comment: You also need to quote the pattern string.

Answer (score 0):

first your % should be like this '%'

```
" AND t1.nombre_cuenta LIKE '%'" +
```